# pass multiple variables to module

Tags: perl

I can't seem to get to figure out how to pass hashrefs to a module correctly.

```
#module helper.pm    

my %helpers;

sub import {
    shift @_; #returns "helper"
    %SOME_CONFIG = %{shift @_};
    foreach my $hashref (%{@_}){
        $helpers{$hashref->{key}} = $hashref->{value};
    }
}

#main

use helper(
    \%SOME_CONFIG,
    "first_helper" => (
        sub {
            return do_something();
        },
        sub {
            return do_something_else();
        }
    ),
    "second_helper" => (
        sub {
            return something_else();
        }
    )
);
```

I'm not sure how to convert the array to a hash correctly. I thought it work because the anonymous function are passed as references. However it still indexes over @_ as if it is an array and the keys become the indexes of @_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your module is not a pragma, i.e. it doesn't change how the code is parsed, use a capitalized name.

Values of hashes mush be scalars, so if you want to assign several subroutines to a key, you must use an array reference.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{
    package Helper;
    my %helpers;

    sub import {
        my $class = shift;
        my %SOME_CONFIG = %{ shift; };
        for my $hashref (@_){
            @helpers{keys %$hashref} = values %$hashref;
        }
        use Data::Dumper;
        $Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1;  # To show the code, as well.
        warn Dumper \%SOME_CONFIG, \%helpers;
    }
}


my %SOME_CONFIG = ( field => 'and its value' );

sub do_something {
    warn "Doing something";
}

sub do_something_else {
    warn "Doing something else";
}

Helper->import(
    \%SOME_CONFIG,
    { first_helpers => [
        \&do_something,
        \&do_something_else,
    ] },
    { second_helpers => [
        sub {
            warn "Inside the 2nd helper";
        },
    ] },
);
```

If you put Helper into a file of its own, Helper.pm, you can then just

```
use Helper (
    \%SOME_CONFIG,
    ....
```

BUT, `use` clauses are processed at compile time, when %SOME_CONFIG still hasn't been populated, so you need to define it in a BEGIN block. You still need to declare it outside the block, though, to make it accessible in the use clause:

```
my %SOME_CONFIG;
BEGIN {
    %SOME_CONFIG = ( field => 'and its value' );
}
```

Simplified as ikegami suggested:

In Helper.pm, just do

```
%helpers = @_;
```

instead of the `for my $hashref`. In the main program, use

```
use Helper(
    \%SOME_CONFIG,
    first_helpers => [
        \&do_something,
        \&do_something_else,
    ],
    second_helpers => [
        sub {
            warn "Inside the 2nd helper";
        },
    ],
);
```

Comment: `{ first_helpers => ..., }, { second_helpers => ... }` should be `{ first_helpers => ..., second_helpers => ... }` (with the appropriate change to `import`)

Answer (score 2):

Lowercase module names are reserved by Perl, and the convention is to use them for pragmas. That's two misses, so let's rename the module to `Helper`. (Don't forget to change the file name to match!)

---

The arguments are

- `"Helper"`
- `\%SOME_CONFIG`
- `"first_helper"`
- `sub { 1 }`
- `sub { 2 }`
- `"second_helper"`
- `sub { 3 }`

You probably meant to pass the sub refs in arrays, but you used parens. Parens just change precedence. Instead, you should have used the following:

```
use Helper (
    \%SOME_CONFIG,
    "first_helper" => [
        sub {
            return do_something();
        },
        sub {
            return do_something_else();
        }
    ],
    "second_helper" => [
        sub {
            return something_else();
        }
    ],
);
```

Now, the arguments are

- `"Helper"`
- `\%SOME_CONFIG`
- `"first_helper"`
- `[ sub { 1 }, sub { 2 } ]`
- `"second_helper"`
- `[ sub { 3 } ]`

There's no hash in there other than `\%SOME_CONFIG`, but you have a hash dereference. That's no good. We could build a hash in the caller, but there's no need to make that any longer since we can handle the data as-is. Solutions:

```
sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    my $config = shift;
    my %new_helpers = @_;
    for my $id (keys(%new_helpers)) {
        $helpers{$id} = $new_helpers{$id};
    }
}
```

or

```
sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    my $config = shift;
    %helpers = ( %helpers, @_ );
}
```

or

```
sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    my $config = shift;
    while (@_) {
       my $id = shift;
       $helpers{$id} = shift;
    }
}
```